# remote log into windows xp running on headless ubuntu server

Tags: virtual-machines

I have a headless machine running Ubuntu Server.
I would like to clone an existing windows xp install to a virtual machine then run that virtual machine on the linux box.  I would then like to use windows RDC to log into the windows virtual machine running on the linux headless box.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. You'll need to

- Clone the existing partition and convert it to a VM image. This will depend on the VM you use, for e.g. VirtualBox it's like this: http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=1404
- install VM on the server, transfer VM image to the server
- start VM on server

As to how to connect to it, RDC is one option (if you have an XP version that supports it); most VMs also have their own technology (see e.g. http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html for VirtualBox).